# What's wrong with my conjecture?

Tags: real-analysis, roots, conjectures

I was doing math homework, and I formulated the following conjecture from one of the questions:
If $f(x)$, $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ are continuous functions and the equations $f(x) = h(x)$ and  $g(x) = h(x)$ both have *only* one root, then the equation $f(x) = g(x)$ has *only* one root. So can anyone find a counterexample? I can't think of one, but maybe that's because I haven't read *Counterexamples in Analysis* yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just take $f(x) = g(x) = x$ and $h(x) = 0$.

If you want a less trivial example, take $f(x) = x + \sin x$, $g(x) = x + \cos x$, and $h(x) = 0$. See it [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=x%2bsin%20x,%20x%2bcos%20x).

For a less trivial $h$, you can take $f(x) = x \sin x$, $g(x) = x \cos x$, and $h(x) = ax$ for any $a$ such that $|a| > 1$). See it [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%20sin%20x,%20x%20cos%20x,%202x) for $a=2$.

I would like to make another example, fundamentally different from the previous ones: $f(x) = -(x+1)^2$, $g(x) = (x-1)^2$, $h(x) = -4x$. Here, your conditions are also met, but $f(x) = g(x)$ has no real solutions. See it [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B%7B-%28x%2b1%29%5E2,%20%28x-1%29%5E2,%20-4x%7D,%7Bx,-2,2%7D%5D).

Comment: I've added another one, to show that $f(x) = g(x)$ doesn't have to have any (real) roots at all.